# how to handle CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value

Tags: node.js, exception, mongoose, node-modules

I am using mongoose and Node.Js for exposing my webservices.
When ever the client send me invalid object id , i am getting the error

```
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "333333707333371ssss" at path "_id" for model "student"',
```

I have a lot of models where i use `.find` and handling everywhere try catch ;is it the right solution?
What is the elegant way to handle this in the whole application? I want to give back a null response back since that object id doesn't correspond to anything...

How to handle this error?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose will fail at casting this ObjectId as it is not a valid one. Before you call a `.find` method, you should check it by using mongoose validator `mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)`. Note that this is a bit "hacky" as you are checking validation inside controller. Otherwise, you could catch an error in callback and respond accordingly.

Comment: Should i write isValid in every controller? I think that will be tough..Is there any alternatives

Comment: Than you should catch and error in find method. Every callback has error and response, so after call, you can check if there was an error. Like .find({}, function(error, data) {})